# Delete Object without calling destructors of member pointers

Tags: c++

I have a class Mesh.

I have another class called Safemesh.

Many safemeshes store a pointer to the same Mesh.

When I call the destructor of a Safemesh, I don't want to delete my Mesh.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: by using [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: Don't write `delete mesh;` and the mesh won't be deleted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I call the destructor of a Safemesh, I don't want to delete my Mesh.
>
> How can I do this?

By not deleting the Mesh pointer in the destructor of Safemesh. If there is nothing else that the destructor needs, or doesn't need to do, then the implicitly generated destructor will be OK.

Example:

```
struct Mesh;
struct Safemesh {
    Mesh* mesh;
};
```

---

This of course leaves you with the task of destroying the meshes elsewhere.

One solution is to store the Meshes in a container and make sure that no element of that container is destroyed before any depending Safemesh is either destroyed or set to point elsewhere. Example:

```
std::vector<Mesh> meshes(2);
Safemesh safe0 { &meshes[0] };
Safemesh safe1 { &meshes[0] };
Safemesh safe2 { &meshes[1] };
Safemesh safe3 { &meshes[1] };
```

Another solution is to use shared ownership: When the last Safemesh that points to a particular Mesh is destroyed, only then will the Mesh be destroyed. This can be achieved by using reference counting. There is a reference counting smart pointer in the standard library: `std::shared_ptr`. Example:

```
struct Safemesh {
   std::shared_ptr<Mesh> mesh;
};
```

Comment: I already have the management figured out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply